# Ignoring or skipping certain commits on Git

Tags: git

I cloned a sample project, but when I check `git log` I see there are about **15 commits**.

Commits 10 and 8 caused problems to the project and for now I would like to remove/ignore/skip changes made in commits 10 and 8.

How can I do this? (I don't want to merge or push these changes).

Comment: You are best off to `git revert` the specific commits. You can then revert the revert to put them back.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `git rebase -i hash_to_your_7th_commit` and delete commits 8 and 10 but you are most likely going to get lots of conflicts.

Another option is `git checkout -b 7th_commit` and `cherry-pick` commits 9 and from 10 to 15.
Keep in mind that if you give a range 10..15 `cherry-pick` will start at 11.

I would recommend though to just `revert` these two commits because you may change your mind about pushing it someday.